# Trigonometric Fourier coefficients calculated with numpy FFT off by a factor of two

Tags: numpy, fft

I'm trying to calculate the trigonometric Fourier coefficients (i.e. Eq. (1) from the [Fourier series Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)) using the FFT algorithms in numpy. From the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details), it appears that the inverse DFT is as given in [this math stack exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1709583/683123) so that if Xm is the DFT and n is the number of points, then Am = (1/n) Re[Xm] and Bm = -(1/n) Im[Xm].

However, when I actually try to calculate these, the trigonometric Fourier coefficients are off by a factor of 2. I've tried to check on the normalization by using the inverse DFT from numpy, but that gives back the original input. [Here's a github gist](https://gist.github.com/lucasmyers97/1ef9aa79e29c8dfaa64828da15fdb405) which tries to demonstrate the problem. What am I doing wrong here, and where could that factor of 2 be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy is unrelated to the numpy implementation, and is just a math fact. In the linked answer, j <= N/2 corresponds to the positive-frequency components and j > N/2 to the negative frequency components. This can be verified by doing a change of variables for the latter sum from j -> N - m. For real-valued functions, the negative-frequency components are necessarily the complex conjugate of the positive-frequency components This must be the case because the imaginary parts must sum to zero. However, this also means that the components as I have defined them only account for the positive-frequency components, and so must be scaled by 2.